# How do I reupload my files to missing files in remote server?

Tags: git

Recently my server has been compromised, the files are deleted in this remote server.

I have a backup, I tried to execute command:

```
git push live master --force
```

But I got this in the console:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

It seems the files aren't uploaded in the server...

How do I reupload the files as backup to this remote server?

Comment: Your *git* server had files deleted (as in `git rm`)?

Comment: @crashmstr I don't think so, some folders were not deleted, then most files are deleted by manual.